# Hygieia Github Collector is not fetching old commits

Tags: github, hygieia

My github-scm-collector is not fetching commits from last 7 days, Rather it is showing only recent commits. How to solve this Problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to class com.capitalone.dashboard.collector.GitHubCollectorTask
Line 193,

```
 boolean firstRun = true; // ((repo.getLastUpdated() == 0) || ((start - repo.getLastUpdated()) > FOURTEEN_DAYS_MILLISECONDS));
```

Make this change and run it again.